# p2p without flex sdk via clean actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, p2p, adobe-stratus

Is it possible to write p2p app without flex sdk on clean actionscript via Stratus ofc?

Because 1mb size of flex sdk it's a bit kinda too much.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. P2P API don't have any dependency with the Flex SDK.

BTW, if you want to reduce Flex application size, use RSL.

Comment: Yea i know what is RSL. :) But it does not garantee that user will have sdk cached. Thanks thou, i'll look into it then. ;)